# Values adding up in the last bin of an histogram

Tags: matplotlib

Consider this minimum example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = np.arange(0,5,1)
N = [0,1,2,3,4,5,5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10))
plt.hist(N, bins=bins, width=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Why is the last bin empty, and the second last is the sum of the last and the second last?

[image: t]

Comment: Your bin edges are `[0,1,2,3,4]`. Hence there is no bin that can contain `5`. The last bin contains `3` and `4` and hence shows double the frequency of the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [plt.hist()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) documentation:

> If bins is a sequence, it defines the bin edges, including the left edge of the first bin and the right edge of the last bin [...] All but the last (righthand-most) bin is half-open. In other words, if bins is: [1, 2, 3, 4] 
>   then the first bin is [1, 2) (including 1, but excluding 2) and the second [2, 3). The last bin, however, is [3, 4], which includes 4.

In your example, `bins = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, so the last bin is [3, 4], which includes both 3 and 4. The two values of 5 are not depicted at all, since they fall outside the range you implicitly specified with `bins`.

To get a more intuitive result, you could set `bins = np.arange(0, 7, 1) - .5` instead. In this way you cover the whole data range, and none of the values lies on a bin border.

Comment: Then if I set `bins = np.arange(0,4,1)` and `N = [0,1,2]`, I understand that my bins are `[0,1)`, `[1,2)`, and `[2,3]` (one for each value in `N`), yet I obtain three bars with size 1. I would expect three bars with increasing size.

Comment: Why should the bar size increase? `plt.hist()` is designed to plot a histogram, which means counting the number of values in each bin and plotting a bar whose length is proportional to that count. This is not cumulative in any way. In the language of probability theory, the histogram shows the (empirical) distribution, not the cumulative distribution function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram Having said that, you can use `plt.hist(..., cumulative=True)` if that's what you want.